# Z-Index not working in Tailwind CSS React JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

How can make the calendar pop up? I am using tailwind CSS, it won't work. I tried to follow the documentation about the z-index.

This is my main homepage. And it's arranged completely.

```
  const Homepage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Header />
      <UnderHeader />
      <div className="mt-14 flex flex-col items-center gap-8">
        <Featured />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is UnderHeader.jsx where the content of search box, date etc.

```
 return (
    <div className="w-screen h-80 max-h-7xl drop-shadow-lg  ">
      <div
        className="w-full h-full mt-5 bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center opacity-100 bg-neutral-800  bg-blend-overlay flex items-center justify-center "
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${BackgroundIsland})` }}
      >
        <div className="flex items-center justify-evenly p-4 w-3/4 h-16 text-lg border-2 border-white/[.2] bg-white/[.08] rounded-full">
          <div className="flex gap-3 items-center  justify-center text-white">
            <FaBed size={36} className="" />
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Location..."
              className="px-3 border-b-2 py-1 text-dark focus:outline-none w-72 bg-transparent cursor-pointer"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex gap-3 cursor-pointer text-white items-center relative z-50 justify-center">
            <FcCalendar size={36} className="text-white" />
            <p onClick={() => setOpenDate(!openDate)}>
              {`${format(date[0].startDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}`}
              <span className="mx-2 font-thin">to</span>
              {`${format(date[0].endDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}`}
            </p>
            {openDate && (
              <DateRange
                editableDateInputs={true}
                onChange={(item) => setDate([item.selection])}
                moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
                ranges={date}
                className="absolute top-[50px]"
              />
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="flex gap-3 text-white items-center justify-center relative">
            <HiUserGroup size={36} className="" />
            <p
              className="cursor-pointer"
              onClick={() => setOpenOptions(!openOptions)}
            >{`${options.adult} adult • ${options.children} children • ${options.room} room`}</p>
            {openOptions && (
              <div className="absolute top-[50px] bg-white text-gray-800 rounded-sm px-3 py-4 drop-shadow-2xl">
                {/* This is person choose */}
                <ButtonHeader
                  title="Adult"
                  buttonName="adult"
                  quantity={options.adult}
                  handleOption={handleOption}
                />
                <ButtonHeader
                  disabled={options.children <= 1}
                  title="Children"
                  buttonName="children"
                  quantity={options.children}
                  handleOption={handleOption}
                />
                <ButtonHeader
                  disabled={options.room <= 1}
                  title="Room"
                  buttonName="room"
                  quantity={options.room}
                  handleOption={handleOption}
                />
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="flex gap-1 cursor-pointer bg-blue-200 hover:bg-blue-300 duration-300 rounded-full px-4 py-3 items-center justify-center">
            <FcSearch size={24} className="" />
            <p className="text-lg font-bold">Search</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

This is featured.jsx that contains the image, which, and it is under the header.jsx

```
const Featured = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full max-w-5xl flex justify-between gap-4 ">
      <div className="w-full object-cover relative">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472213984618-c79aaec7fef0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=855&q=80"
          alt=""
          className="w-full object-fit  z-[1]"
        />
        <div className="text-white rounded-lg h-64 absolute bottom-4">
          <p className="text-5xl absolute">Dublin</p>
          <p className="text-5xl absolute">123 Properties</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Featured
```

[image]

live demo: https://booking-ui-sand.vercel.app/

repo: https://github.com/Zurcemozz/bookingUI

Comment: Where's your working demo?

Comment: @LeeTaylor please check again

Comment: You problem is that you are placing the whole calendar in the same part of the dom as the element that was clicked on. If you put the calendar so that its only parent is body you will notice that the calendar is now located correctly **above** all else. However, the next step is to position the top and left parts of the calendar div to locate it correctly horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind allows the use of negative values. You could try to use the class `-z-10` instead of using the inline style.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a great approach, I inline code the CSS to the feature and make it negative. is there any way to apply it in tailwind CSS?

```
 const Featured = () => {
      return (
        <div className="w-full max-w-7xl flex justify-space-between gap-4 ">
          <div
            className="relative text-white  drop-shadow-lg h-64"
            style={{ zIndex: -1 }}
          >
            <img
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1511515828069-1e4853d8b336?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
              alt=""
              className="w-full object-cover"
            />
            <div className="absolute bottom-5 left-4">
              <p className="text-7xl">Dublin</p>
              <p className="text-5xl">123 Properties</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Featured
```